# Is there a Blueprint Plugin for reverse (white on black) typography?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I'm using the Blueprint CSS framework for a website.  Some pages I'm developing have a black background.

Although I can set all the styles myself, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a plugin I could use to do this for me.

Comment: Being such a trivial matter, I'm going to say I doubt it exists. Just create a set of styles, and call the appropriate class when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, lots of searching suggests that there is no such plug-in.

The nearest thing I have been able to find exists in the Compass project: http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/blueprint/colors/, which at least allows you to set everything up as constants in SASS or SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

A framework can help you but cannot do all the job for you!

I think it's easy change the background and font color when you want.

Comment: That's true, but I prefer to use code that is maintained collaboratively wherever possible.